# Execute SQL query in another Query as result

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

I have a table which contains SQL query as one of the columns. Based on record id, I want to execute SQL query which is in the record.

```
Master_Table
------------------------------
|Rec_ID | Query              |
------------------------------
|1      | SELECT * from EMP  |
------------------------------
|2      | SELECT * FROM DEPT |
------------------------------
```

```sql
SELECT Query FROM Master_Table WHERE Rec_ID=1
```

I am expecting that If I select Rec_Id =1, I have to EMP records.
If I select Rec_Id=2, I need to get Dept records.

Is it possible to do it in SQL query?

Comment: You can't do this with straight SQL. You could do this in a procedure by selecting first from this table, then dynamically executing the sql that is pulled from that first query using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` [see here about Dynamic SQL in a Stored Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to run dynamic SQL in SQL.  In 18c we can use a polymorphic table function.  If it's OK to get the results as XML we can use `DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML`.  If we're able to create custom PL/SQL objects we can use Oracle data cartridge to build a [Method4](https://github.com/method5/method4) solution.

For example, after installing Method4, we can run SQL like this:

```
select * from table(method4.dynamic_query(
    '
        select query
        from master_table
        where rec_id = 1
    '
));
```

The above code will work with the below sample schema:

```
create table master_table as
select 1 rec_id, 'SELECT * from EMP'  query from dual union all
select 2 rec_id, 'SELECT * FROM DEPT' query from dual;

create table emp(emp_name varchar2(100));
create table dept(dept_name varchar2(100));
```

The preceding information literally answers your question.  But I agree with Mark D Powell that this design is often a bad idea and we should only create code like this after we've evaluated alternative designs.

Answer (score 0):

Vsau, I agree with JNevill in that you need PL/SQL to execute the 'SQL' from your table column.  Also I will add that these kind of designs are usually a bad idea.  You want your application SQL to be static sql using bind variables otherwise your system will suffer from too high a percentage of hard parses and resulting contention on the dictionary objects and you may run into shared pool fragmentation issues.

Comment: Thanks JNevil and Mark. First time I am using this concept, due project requirement. I will create a stored procedure or will have to look for another approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys_refcursor`

```
SQL> create or replace function get_emp_tab return sys_refcursor is
  v_rc  sys_refcursor;
  v_sql varchar2(4000);
begin
  select query into v_sql from Master_Table where Rec_ID = 1
  open v_rc for v_sql;
  return v_rc;
end;
/
SQL> declare
       v_rc sys_refcursor;
begin
   :v_rc := get_emp_tab;
end;
/
SQL> print v_rc;
```